# Rabbitmq stomp connection failure

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

i am a complete beginner trying to make a basic web-messaging service with rabbitmq, stomp and sock js, im following a tutorial and have done all the things written there but connection keeps failing. i cant figure out why any help will be appreciated

this is my listenr-app.js file:

```
// Use SockJS
Stomp.WebSocketClass = SockJS;

// Connection parameters
var mq_username = "guest",
    mq_password = "guest",
    mq_vhost    = "/",
    mq_url      = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + ':15674/stomp',

    // The queue we will read. The /topic/ queues are temporary
    // queues that will be created when the client connects, and
    // removed when the client disconnects. They will receive
    // all messages published in the "amq.topic" exchange, with the
    // given routing key, in this case "mymessages"
    mq_queue    = "/topic/mymessages";

// This is where we print incomoing messages
var output;

// This will be called upon successful connection
function on_connect() {
  output.innerHTML += 'Connected to RabbitMQ-Web-Stomp<br />';
  console.log(client);
  client.subscribe(mq_queue, on_message);
}

// This will be called upon a connection error
function on_connect_error() {
  output.innerHTML += 'Connection failed!<br />';
}

// This will be called upon arrival of a message
function on_message(m) {
  console.log('message received'); 
  console.log(m);
  output.innerHTML += m.body + '<br />';
}

// Create a client
var client = Stomp.client(mq_url);

window.onload = function () {
  // Fetch output panel
  output = document.getElementById("output");

  // Connect
  client.connect(
    mq_username,
    mq_password,
    on_connect,
    on_connect_error,
    mq_vhost
  );
};
```

this is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Testing RabbitMQ Web Stomp</title>

    <!-- From: http://cdn.sockjs.org/ --> 
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/sockjs/0.3.4/sockjs.min.js"></script>

    <script src="resources/js/stomp.js"></script>

 <!-- From RabbitMQ-Web-Stomp examples -->


    <!-- Our example app -->
    <script src="listener-app.js"></script>

    <style>
      #output {
        border: 1px solid black;
        min-height: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <h1>Waiting for messages</h1>

    <div id="output">
      <!-- incoming messages will be printed here -->
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You say the connection keeps failing. Do you have the error message from the failing connection. And is your rabbitmq actually running? You can check that by browsing to the url. You should get the login page. Also make sure the permissions for `guest` are configured in rabbitmq

Comment: It says opening web socket and then the error message says "whoops lost connection to undefined". I have checked , my rabbitmq is running. Also the permissions for guest are its default settings. And the connections are being established through a java class but not through a stompjs

Comment: Do you see the `topic` queue appear/disappearing like the comments say. Did you debug in the browser? Are `on_connect`/`on_error` called. What did you try?